# How to configure Git to remove certain lines before commit, for both local files and commit?

Tags: bash, git, git-commit, gitattributes

Because of a tool that I use, certain comment lines keeps being added to my code.

```java
// Added by blahblah
```

Since I can't turn off this behavior, I want to configure Git to automatically remove that comment line from both local file and commit.

I want to configure Git to do these:

1. Remove `// Added by blahblah` comment lines
   There can be multiple Tab or Space in front of the comments I want to remove.
   The comments must be removed for both local files and commit.
2. Re-stage modified files
   I'm not sure if this is needed or not, but if it is needed, it should do so.

So, after Git completes its job, the comment lines must be removed from both local file and commit (and remote repository too).

---

First thing I've tried was using IDEA's [File Watchers](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177-file-watchers) plugin.

If I register a script that removes that comment line, the problem would be solved because the comment line is removed before Git creates commit and the commit won't have that comment line.
So 'No comment in local file, No comment in commit too'.

I wrote a bash script for it.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# this script is located at '.script' directory
scriptdir="$(dirname -- "$0")"
cd "$scriptdir/../src" || exit

java_files=$(find . -type f -name "*.java")

for java_file in $java_files; do
  sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' "$java_file"
done
```

But File Watchers kept running when I enable my watcher task.
I expected the task to be run only once for every file save, but it kept running infinitely.
Because File Watchers task is executed every seconds, it conflicted with currently opened editor's content. This prevented me to edit code at all.

So I gave up using File Watchers plugin.

---

Next thing I've tried was using Git Hooks.

In my *theory*, if I set Git Hooks correctly, Git would edit my local files before making any commit. Since my local files are edited before commit, both local files and files in the commit won't have such comment lines.

I wrote `prepare-commit-msg` like this.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# this script is located at '.git/hooks' directory
print "$PWD"
scriptdir="$(dirname -- "$0")"
cd "$scriptdir/../../src" || exit
echo "$PWD"
java_files=$(find . -type f -name "*.java")

for java_file in $java_files; do
  sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' "$java_file"
done
```

But nothing were changed as if there was no such hook present. `pre-commit` also didn't work.

Here is updated version of the `prepare-commit-msg`, but this doesn't work either.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TMP_FILE=$(mktemp)

for FILE in $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM); do
  if [[ $FILE == *.java ]]; then
    sed -e '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' "$FILE" > "$TMP_FILE"
    cat "$TMP_FILE" > "$FILE"
    git add "$FILE"
    # This doesn't work neither
    #sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' "$FILE"
    #git add "$FILE"
  fi
done

exit 0
```

---

Last thing I've tried was to use `.gitattributes`'s `filter`.

I added these line into `.gitconfig`.

```
[filter "nocomment"]
    clean = "sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*\\/\\/ Added by blahblah/d' %f"
    smudge = ""
    required = true
```

And this line to `.gitattributes`.

```
*.java filter=nocomment
```

Since I only need to 'remove' lines, not 'restore' them, I left `smudge` as empty.

But this didn't remove the comment line from local file. Git might remove that line for commit, but that's not what I want.

(I'm using Git for Windows, and this might be the reason of something doesn't work properly...?)

---

Here is working `pre-commit` script's content.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -x # This thing is new... Thanks for the information!
for FILE in $(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM); do # '--diff-filter' is needed
  if [[ $FILE == *.java ]]; then # I only have to process java file
    echo Removing comment from ${FILE}
    sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' "$FILE"
    git add "$FILE" # This line was already in second attempt
  fi
done
```

The reason that Git hooks didn't run as if they weren't present was I set `git config --global core.hooksPath` before. This prevented hooks in `.git/hooks` from running...

Now everything works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: I would look more in the direction of the git hook to understand why it's not working.

Comment: Your filters work for me. I created a new test repo, added your filter description (just copied with mouse from your question) to `.git/config`, created a `.gitattributes` with content `*.txt filter=nocomment`, created a `xxx.txt` file with random content interleaved with `// Added by blahblah` comments with spaces and tabs, and committed the file. All comments disappeared from the local file (I must admit I didn't check committed one).

Comment: @GaëlJ I updated the question for another `prepare-commit-msg` hook script. Unfortunately, even though I inspected the output of the some line, it didn't work.

Comment: @phd That's very weird, because I get some error saying: `sed: cannot rename src/sedUcOsWa: Device or resource busy` and `error: external filter 'sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' %f' failed 4`.

Comment: `prepare-commit-msg` is for setting up the message, not altering the staged files. The [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) even say explicitly _it should not be used as replacement for pre-commit hook_.

Comment: When you set up the `pre-commit` hook as shown, what was the output? You printed lots of state but haven't shared any with us

Comment: @Useless That's because there really was nothing to share. Just same as output message telling me commit was done, like `[main 57c993d] test2`, `1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)` and that's all I get. No error message, commit wasn't aborted etc. But the comment lines I want to remove are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to comment on the IDEA FileWatcher plugin, because an IDE is not a substitute for proper automation.

> Next thing I've tried was using Git Hooks.

These are well-documented, [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks).

> I wrote prepare-commit-msg like this

But the linked docs explicitly say

> *It should not be used as replacement for `pre-commit` hook.*

It's just for altering the message, after the staged changes are final. Let's pretend you wrote your script as the correct hook instead, `pre-commit`.

There are a few mistakes in both of your attempts, but you could have debugged them all quickly by adding `set -x` at the top and just running the script. You don't need git to invoke it for you, just test it yourself.

If we combine the unbroken parts of both, it is only missing one thing: you changed the working tree, but didn't stage your changes for inclusion in the commit.

```
useless@stackoverflow:~/Source/so/pchook $ cat .git/hooks/pre-commit
#!/bin/sh
#
set -x
for FILE in $(git diff --cached --name-only)
do
  sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d' "$FILE"
  git add "$FILE" ### this was missing
done
```

Proof:

```
useless@stackoverflow:~/Source/so/pchook $ git diff
diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index f2affac..d8767dd 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -5,7 +5,7 @@ should be
 unaffected // or with comments excluding the special phrase
 // added by "blahblah"
 except without quotes. // like // Added by blahblah
-
+    // Added by blahblah
 EOF or something
 
 
useless@stackoverflow:~/Source/so/pchook $ git commit -am'test'
+ git diff --cached --name-only
+ sed -i /^[[:space:]]*\/\/ Added by blahblah/d test.txt
+ git add test.txt
[master 7ba7949] test
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
useless@stackoverflow:~/Source/so/pchook $ git show HEAD
commit 7ba79490edbf9afc54ac5e4458323f25803ddba3 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Useless <useless@stackoverflow.com>
Date:   Wed Aug 16 21:23:45 2023 +0100

    test

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index f2affac..66b45b6 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -5,7 +5,6 @@ should be
 unaffected // or with comments excluding the special phrase
 // added by "blahblah"
 except without quotes. // like // Added by blahblah
-
 EOF or something
 
 
useless@stackoverflow:~/Source/so/pchook $
```

Comment: I set `git config --global core.hooksPath` before, and that was the reason my Git hooks didn't work. I updated the question for 'working script'. Thank you a lot!